# grep поиск "-o"

Tags: grep

пытаюсь в файле найти вхождение "-o"
при помощи grep, но никак не получается
пробовал  grep с разными параметрами:

```
grep '-o' file.txt
grep '\<-o' file.txt
grep '\<.o' file.txt
grep '^(-o)' file.txt
```

ничего не сработало, почему то grep знак "-" никак не хочет считать за начало слова

Comment: `... -- -o ...`